# Are "upcoming-books" questions considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we deal with questions about rumors and release dates?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates)

An example is: [Future Malazan novels by Steven Erikson?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2488/future-malazan-novels-by-steven-erikson)

At first glance, I would argue that such questions **should be off-topic** for the following reasons:

- Most likely, there IS no valid answer in the first place. Only rumors.
- In rare cases when some actual info is present, it's usually in a trivial place (Amazon listing for the author, Wikipedia, author's or publisher's web site). Those "let me wiki that for you" questions are off topic.
- In even rarer cases when there IS a non-trivial valid answer (e.g. a quote from an interview, a cite from something the author said at a convention), in most cases it will be 100% obsolete and useless very soon once the book is actually published.

If the community agrees with this logic, should this category be discussed on ["What questions are on-topic, and what questions are off-topic?" thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topicz) and/or added to FAQ?

Comment: I think either there's no valid answer, or the valid answer is too localized, as it's "only relevant to a specific moment in time".  Once the book in question is out, then it's not relevant.  Maybe they would be on topic if reworded into a 'reading order' question, but for many series there's just one obvious reading order, the publication order.

Comment: My personal internal conflict is how do we draw a sharp line between keeping questions like [Are there any plans for a new Babylon 5 series or movies?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/48/35), while at the same time disallowing questions that are quickly obsoleted and frankly uninteresting.

Comment: There's already a very similar question, so I closed yours as a duplicate. Feel free to contribute your opinion as an answer/comment/vote on that thread.

Comment: @Mark - If you DO want to draw a line, do it using the reverse logic of my "contra" arguments above. E.g. only allow the ones that pertain to sure-to-have-an-answer situation (e.g. there's a known fact/statement about the existence of future work); AND when the time-frame is significant enough to warrant not worrying about immediate obsolescence (e.g. known to be >=5 years to pick a random number). Also, the answer must be exact  and non-trivial (the linked B5 question's answers are good examples of such, actually)

Comment: @Gilles - I will repost this as an answer, thanks!