# Should questions asking about the future of a franchise, series, or literary work (groupings) be permitted?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we deal with questions about rumors and release dates?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates)

Recently, even I asked, questions referring to the future or the "future plans of" have been showing up hear and there on our site. Some of these questions are understandable for a long running series, but I don't think these questions add to our knowledge base (if you will). This questions are speculative at best, and may not be given a definitive answer and could change in the future based of obscure contracts and rumors in the media industry.

Should these questions be permitted on our site?

Now I'm not talking about questions about the "future of" a universe (in-universe questions) like "said character did this, what happened afterwards" because it may bring to light some new materials about the universe that many did not discover. Like my Matrix question. I'm asking about the validity of asking questions about the "future production of" or the "future plans of" said franchise.

Like questions

- [Is the Stargate storyline continued after Stargate: Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3461/whats-next-for-the-stargate-franchise)
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96/are-there-any-plans-for-a-new-star-trek-tv-series
- [Plans for more sequels to Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/568/plans-for-more-sequels-to-star-wars)
- [Are there any plans for a new Babylon 5 series or movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48/are-there-any-plans-for-a-new-babylon-5-series-or-movies)

Unlike questions

- [In the Matrix, what happened after the humans and the robots formed a truce?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3465/in-the-matrix-what-happened-after-the-humans-and-the-robots-have-formed-a-truce)
- [In the novels, what happens to the Doctor and the others on Voyager after it returns home?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/468/in-the-novels-what-happens-to-the-doctor-and-the-others-on-voyager-after-it-retu)

Borderline Questions

- [Are there any details about the plot of the cancelled 5th season of the 4400?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2216/are-there-any-details-about-the-plot-of-the-cancelled-5th-season-of-the-4400)

Comment: We've [had this discussion before](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233). It's not clear to me that the community's dominant position hasn't changed since then, but I'm going to ask you to please 1. read the existing discussion and 2. add your arguments to the existing thread, if the existing answers don't satisfy you.

Comment: Thanks Gills, I'll read and post my argument.

Answer (score 3):

How would you answer such questions, exactly?

You're asking the wrong people.  The only people who know the answers to such questions are the franchise owners, and since these answers will change over time (i.e. they become obsolete as the subject of the question gets fulfilled, or not), the question itself is too localized.

Answer (score 1):

I think questions on the future of a sci-fi/fantasy franchise (if the franchise's future is truly uncertain) have merit on the site. While they may not generate as interesting answers as other questions, they will generate traffic to the site.

For instance, there are several questions open now asking the status of the next release in a series of books, and it seems to be an acceptable question.

Aside from that, these types of questions are no different from the story identification questions, and those seem to be generally accepted.

Comment: Story identification questions generally have a definitive answer, if the question is asked well enough.

Comment: "While they may not generate as interesting answers as other questions, they will generate traffic to the site."  I think it's in the best interest of the community to get traffic by having interesting content, not just have traffic for traffic's sake.