# Are questions relating to author statements about future real-world fictional works on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

Today I read a question asking if there had been any official statements about whether a forthcoming Marvel Cinematic Universe film’s storyline would cross over with other films in the series:

- [Are there any official statements on whether Guardians of the Galaxy crosses over with other MCU movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63278/will-there-be-any-crossover-of-guardians-of-the-galaxy-with-current-storyline-of)

The question specifically asked about the existence of statements, so it’s not really speculative. But it did ask for statements that related to the content of a movie that’s coming out in less than three weeks.

It struck me as pretty localized, and thus maybe off-topic (as per [this meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates)). Is that right? (And if so, what’s would be the appropriate close reason?)

([See also this question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/530/should-questions-asking-about-the-future-of-a-franchise-series-or-literary-wor) [And maybe this one?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4762/movie-trailer-based-questions))

Comment: Since we no longer have a "too localized" close reason, I think any existing meta answers defining what is or isn't "too localized" are rendered moot. That said, one of the mods said we could get "too localized" back if we really wanted it.

Comment: Sure, and general reference isn’t a close reason either. Cool cool, so not a vote-to-close question then.

Comment: @phantom42 I'd vote for bringing it back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say any question that requests official information, rather than speculation, is likely acceptable.  It may or may not be a *good* question, but it is probably one that can stay open.

If there is specific reason to suspect further information may exist (hints in a press release or interview, precedent from other works in the series, similar patterns in the materials the work is based off of), questions like this can be quite good.

Of course, in the absence of such sources, questions like this can also be quite bad, and even good questions may result in answers of "no" or "we don't know yet".

Still, I don't think that is sufficient for closure.

Comment: I must admit that "The answer will be known in 3 weeks" does make me uncharacteristically wish for "too localized" close reason.

Comment: @DVK You can use a custom off-topic close reason, and explain why the question has no lasting value. That's the official advice for the very rare cases where “too localized” was warranted: “too localized” was removed not because it wasn't a reason to close but because it was so rarely used correctly (i.e. “too localized” was too localized). Be sure to explain why the question should be closed, don't use the jargon “too localized” which only SE veterans understand.

Comment: @Gilles - Thanks! Good idea!