# Are release date questions still off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, closing-questions

I was reviewing [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117238/i-am-dreaming-now-waiting-to-know-what-happens-withparralells) and it seems to me that [this meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/how-do-we-deal-with-questions-about-rumors-and-release-dates) should apply, and that the question would be off-topic as *too localized*. However, when trying to flag it as such, I found that the *too localized* close reason no longer exists - does this indicate that release date questions are now on-topic for the site, and if not, how should they be appropriately flagged?

(I should note that as originally written, the main answerable "question" I could see was whether a sequel will be coming out - if that is not retained, the overall question of release dates remains.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is a bit complex, because there's multiple parts to it.

1. *Too localized* is no longer a close reason; it was abandoned a while ago, and *in general* we **don't** close questions for the kind of reasons that it covered. The same goes for *not constructive*, the other close reason that covered release-date questions.
2. We have had *similar* recent questions, e.g. about DVD releases of Netflix shows, or HD releases of certain movies, that remained open. To me, this means the community is **no longer actively closing** those kinds of questions -- and there aren't very many of them so I don't think there's much need to.
3. However, the question you referenced isn't really a good example of a release date question; the *core* of that question is asking for details about the resolution of some plot details from the movie. I don't think the OP was really asking "when is this thing being released" so much as they were expressing frustration, e.g. they really meant something like "come on Netflix, how hard is this, go release this already,"
4. In light of #3, and the edits that were made to it, I think the question now deserves to be closed per our Future Works policy: none of those questions have answers, and likely won't have answers, until more material from that show comes out.

Comment: If #2 is true, should the now-inaccurate question referenced be closed as a duplicate to this one, or maybe both can be a duplicate of a third, community post on release dates? I've seen this mechanism used before to update out-of-date questions.